# Create multindex columns from values within pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have read around about this and tried a few different things but can't find anything that meets the exact problem, and also can't figure it out based on solutions that are similar. I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
|ID | Date | Value 1 | Value 2 |
|---|------|---------|---------|
|A  |2019  |100      |150      |
|A  |2020  |120      |250      |
|B  |2019  |5        |10       |
|B  |2020  |6        |4        |
```

I am trying to create a multindex column dataframe like this while simultaneously pivoting:

```
|   |Value 1 |        |Value 2  |         |
|   |2019    |2020    |2019     |2020     |
|---|--------|--------|---------|---------|
|A  |100     |120     |150      |250      |
|B  |5       |6       |10       |4        |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['ID','Date']).unstack()
```

Or [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) without parameter `values`:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Date')
```

Comment: Ahhh so simple. Thanks very much